# Can I customize the messages available in "Message & decline"?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

On receiving a call, there is the option "Message & decline". There are some messages to select from, but none of them fits my needs. (Usually I want to call back later.) Can I create and add a message to this list myself?

Comment: I have not seen the optionto, but agree that this would be a really good feature. If there is not the option, it may be worth raising a nre feature requrst for this in Launchpad.